# How can I copy only the style of a border in sketchapp?

Tags: sketch-app, layer-style

I don't want to copy the whole style of a button. I only want to copy the style of border. Is it even possible? Thanks ^^

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we have these two buttons:
[image: Only copy the border style of a layer - Step1]

1. Download **Automate Sketch** Plugin from [this](https://github.com/Ashung/Automate-Sketch) link
2. Install it (unzip and double click on automate-sketch.sketchplugin)
3. Right click on your first button and select **copy style**

[image: Only copy the border style of a layer - Step2]

4. Select your second button
5. click on **Plugin -> Automate -> Style -> Paste Borders**

[image: Only copy the border style of a layer - Step3]

6. Done. ;)

[image: Only copy the border style of a layer - Step4]

Comment: Can you try "Paste Style" instead?

Comment: If you use "Paste Style", all styles including border, shadow, fill will paste. In this question, we only want to paste the border style.